# Running macro (to assign linked cells to all checkboxes on given sheets) on all files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to reassign all the linked cells for checkboxes on three given worksheets in a large collection of workbooks.

The macro I have works successfully on any book I have open:

```
Sub CheckBoxesControl()

On Error Resume Next

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 400
        Sheet4.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AA" & i
        Sheet21.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AB" & i
        Sheet22.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AC" & i

    Next i

End Sub
```

However I want to run this across a large number of sheets, so I tried the following:

```
Sub CheckBoxesControl()

On Error Resume Next
    Dim path As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim wkbk As Workbook
    Dim i As Long


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    path = "C:\file\path\"
    file = Dir(path)

    Do While Not file = ""
        Workbooks.Open (path & file)
        Set wkbk = ActiveWorkbook

    For i = 1 To 400
        Sheet4.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AA" & i
        Sheet21.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AB" & i
        Sheet22.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AC" & i

    Next i

    wkbk.Save
    wkbk.Close
    file = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

The macro certainly opens and closes each file, and runs without error, but it is not having the desired affect.

It only changes the check boxes for the sheet I run the macro from still (despite apparently opening saving and closing all the others).

Am I failing to correctly set the active workbook?

**EDIT 1: Suggested fix (failed)**

Method suggested in comments (proved unsuccessful):

```
Sub CheckBoxesControl()

On Error Resume Next
    Dim path As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim wkbk As Workbook
    Dim i As Long


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    path = "C:\file\path\"
    file = Dir(path)

    Do While Not file = ""

        Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(path & file)
    For i = 1 To 400
        wkbk.Sheet4.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AA" & i
        wkbk.Sheet21.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AB" & i
        wkbk.Sheet22.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AC" & i
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then

        End If
    Next i

    wkbk.Save
    wkbk.Close
    file = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

**EDIT 2: REMOVING ON ERROR RESUME NEXT**

Suggestedion to remove the error ignoring has illustrated the following: when the macro runs an error:

Run-time error 1004
The item with the specific name wasn't found.

Debugging this error highlights:

```
Sheet4.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AA" & i
```

I believe I realise what this issue is: I'm using a "go between 1 and 400" loop to ensure I catch all the checkboxes on each page, but there isn't a checkbox for each one of those instances, (checkbox1 doesn't exist for example, on all pages - notably not on sheet 4)

I remember now this is why I had On error resume next there in the first place... but I need "next" to be the next "i" in the loop, not the next expression completely.

Comment: Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open (path & file) And then wkbk.Sheet4....

Comment: That doesn't seem to have made any difference? Have edited the question to include the new code I tried to make sure I interpreted your suggestion correctly.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `On Error Resume Next` statement, at least temporarily. That's generally a bad practice, all it's doing is *hiding* real errors, which might be the source of your problem.

Comment: Ah... hold on. You're not actually initiating a loop over files within a folder. You need an FSO to do that. None in your code.

Comment: @David - `Dir()` was around before the FSO came along.  It works fine for looping though files.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams you're correct, I implemented OP's code incorrectly, which was why it wasn't working when I tried it.

Comment: well, if you don't want to try my suggestion since `Dir()` will also work, then perhaps get rid of the `DisplayAlerts = False`, also get rid of `ScreenUpdating=False`, you can turn these back on when you're done debugging. Then, put a breakpoint on `wkbk.Sheet4.CheckBoxes(...` and run your code. Step through the code in debugger. That should set you straight, or at least give us more information about what is possibly going wrong.

Comment: I would agree with @DavidZemens on getting rid of `On Error Resume Next` until you know what errors you are getting and that you really do want to ignore them. After removing that line try it again and see if it works. But i don't agree with the `FSO` method as is my experiences it has ALWAYS been slower then the `DIR()` approach. Especially when looping files in a folder. I have a feeling the issue is with the CheckBoxes and you are getting errors that are being ignored.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice and time. I've done as you suggested and enabled the errors: it seems good advice I now get an error, I'll update the post to reflect this new information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 4**

For those keeping score at home, the problem is that OP was using the sheets `CodeName`, which cannot be used when referring to it from a macro in another spreadsheet.

Modify to accept the worksheet Name, and either of the subs can be called like:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = wkbk.Sheets("10. Prevention Finance")
    UpdateChkBoxes3 ws, "ChkBoxOutput!AA"

    Set ws = wkbk.Sheets("...") '#Modify the sheet name
    UpdateChkBoxes3 ws, "ChkBoxOutput!AB"

    Set ws = wkbk.Sheets("...") '#Modify the sheet name
    UpdateChkBoxes3 ws, "ChkBoxOutput!AC"
```

**Update 3** (non-ActiveX Checkboxes)

```
Sub UpdateChkBoxes3(sht as Worksheet, lnkdCell as String)
Dim cb as CheckBox
Dim cbNum As Integer
With sht
    For Each cb In sht.CheckBoxes
        cbNum = Replace(cb.Name, "Check Box ", vbNullString)
        cb.LinkedCell = lnkdCell & cbNum
    Next
End With
```

I also revised the sub in Update 2, previously had pasted in my testing code, instead of the proper sub that requires sht/lnkdCell as arguments.

**Update 2**

To account for non-indexed checkbox names, but still looping over all checkboxes in each worksheet, call this subroutine. I attempt to get the *numeric* value from the checkbox's `.Name` property, this should relate it to the cell location just like your `i` indexing did before, only you will avoid errors where checkboxes don't exist, because we're not looping over an `Index`, we're looping over the shapes themselves.  This should work with ActiveX checkboxes:

```
Sub UpdateChkBoxes2(sht As Worksheet, lnkdCell As String)
'To address non-sequential/missing check box names not aligned with index
Dim cb As OLEObject
Dim cbNum As Integer
With sht
    For Each cb In sht.OLEObjects
        If cb.progID Like "Forms.CheckBox*" Then
            cbNum = Replace(cb.Name, "Check Box ", vbNullString)
            cb.LinkedCell = lnkdCell & cbNum
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

**Update**

Try something like this, which assumes CheckBoxes are named sequentially according to their index, and that there are no missing indices.

```
UpdateChkBoxes Sheet4, "ChkBoxOutput!AA"
UpdateChkBoxes Sheet21, "ChkBoxOutput!AB"
UpdateChkBoxes Sheet22, "ChkBoxOutput!AC"

'## Replaced the following error-prone code:
'For i = 1 To .CheckBoxes.Count
'    wkbk.Sheet4.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AA" & i
'    wkbk.Sheet21.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AB" & i
'    wkbk.Sheet22.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AC" & i
'    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'
'    End If
'Next i
```

Then, include this subroutine:

```
Sub UpdateChkBoxes(sht as Worksheet, lnkdCell as String)
With sht
    For i = 1 to .CheckBoxes.Count
    .CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = lnkdCell & i
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

**Original Response**

OK, I think the problem is that nothing in your code is actually iterating over the files within a folder. You will need to use a `FileSystemObject` to do this. You can enable reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` dictionary, or, simply declare these variables as generic `Object` instead of `Scripting....`

Create an FSO, then assign a folder, and loop over the `File` objects within this folder. Open the file, and then pass it to a subroutine to perform your checkbox operations.

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub LoopFiles()

'## Requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library

Dim path As String
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim folder As Scripting.folder
Dim file As Scripting.file
Dim wkbk As Workbook
    path = ThisWorkbook.path

    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)

        For Each file In folder.Files
            Select Case UCase(Right(file.Name, 4))  '## Make sure you're only working on XLS file types
                Case "XLSX", "XLSM", ".XLS" 'etc.
                    '
                    Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(file.Name)

                    'Now, send this WOrkbook Object to a subroutine
                    CheckBoxesControl wkbk
                    wkbk.Save
                    wkbk.Close
                Case Else
                    'Do nothing
            End Select
        Next

    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub


Sub CheckBoxesControl(wkbk As Workbook)
    Dim i As Long
    On Error Resume Next

    With wkbk
        For i = 1 To 400
            .Sheet4.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AA" & i
            .Sheet21.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AB" & i
            .Sheet22.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).LinkedCell = "ChkBoxOutput!AC" & i
        Next i
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and work here: as others have commented above I don't believe the Dir method is at fault as I have used this to loop other macros. I appreciate learning more about FSO however as I hadn't crossed it before.

Comment: @Gideon see revised answer, which will loop over checkboxes by their index, from i = 1 to `.CheckBoxes.Count`.  That should avoid an error where, e.g., "Check Box 300" doesn't exist on a sheet, as long as they are named sequentially and consistently with their index #.

Comment: I'll give it a go, but due to editing of the document (before my time) the checkboxes are not, in fact numbered sequentially) More like 3, 7, 35, 12 etc... they are pretty much all over the place, I need something that will just catch all checkboxes on a page. I'll try this though

Comment: Ah! That's a clever approach: I'm getting error "this object does not support property or method". I beleive this is because the "shape" approach only applies to ActiveX controls? My check boxes are all form controls, which I think need to be referenced a different way?

Comment: Try `Dim cb as Variant` maybe.

Comment: OK, revised my answer, ActiveX checkbox is an OLEObject, I've updated my answer above with some changes to account for this.

Comment: Sorry to clarify - my checkboxes are **not** activeX objectes, I'm apologies I thought that "shape" was the way to refer to those, perhaps your original code was correct, however I got "this object does not support property or method" in that case

Comment: Using UpdateChkBoxes3 I'm afraid I still get the error:
`object does not support property or method`
While highlighting 
`UpdateChkBoxes3 wkbk.Sheet4, "ChkBoxOutput!AA"`

I don't know if you are comfortable opening stanger's macro enabled workbooks, but I have put the book in question with three example files to be adjusted in this dropbox file:
[link removed - sorry realised I probably shouldn't share that completely openly, will chat it toy you]

Master Book, VB Module 6 contains the sub you've been working on (file path will need editing).

Comment: OK I see what the problem is...  since `wkbk` is already the `ActiveWorkbook`, let's try omitting that from the sub call, like:  `UpdateChkBoxes3 Sheet4, "ChkBoxOutput!AA"`.  I think that will work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31690/discussion-between-gideon-and-david-zemens)

Comment: Cheers! There are not many times that Excel will beat me; I was determined not to let this be one of them! :)